# error running mvn checkstyle:checkstyle

Tags: java, maven, plugins, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I get the following error when executing the command `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle`:

```
An error has occurred in Checkstyle report generation.
...
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate GenericIllegalRegexp
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:178)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.executeCheckstyle(DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java:170)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.AbstractCheckstyleReport.executeReport(AbstractCheckstyleReport.java:259)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Unable to instantiate GenericIllegalRegexp
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.PackageObjectFactory.createModule(PackageObjectFactory.java:155)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.setupChild(TreeWalker.java:161)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:184)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:157)
... 27 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Unable to instantiate GenericIllegalRegexpCheck
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.PackageObjectFactory.doMakeObject(PackageObjectFactory.java:98)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.PackageObjectFactory.createModule(PackageObjectFactory.java:152)
    ... 30 more
```

I guess the error has to do with the rules created with an older version of checkstyle.

The checkstyle plugin configuration inside the pom.xml is:

```
...
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.9.1</version>
<configuration>
    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
    <headerLocation>LICENSE.txt</headerLocation>
</configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Is there a way or tool to migrate the rules to make them checkstyle 5.5 compatible? (Other than overviewing rule per rule based on the checkstyle documentaion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to get rid of that particular exception modifying the xml of the rules. 
I've  replaced:

```
<module name="GenericIllegalRegexp">
  <property name="format" value="\s+$"/>
  <property name="message" value="Line has trailing spaces."/>
  <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
</module>
```

with

```
<module name="RegexpSinglelineJava">
  <property name="format" value="\s+$"/>
  <property name="message" value="Line has trailing spaces."/>
  <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Hope I helped someone with the same problem. Regards.